# Market Application (process com.android.vending) has stopped unexpectedly

Tags: google-play-store, system-error

I have an HTC Android running 2.2. The market application was running perfectly before I  updated it.

It was when the Google changed Market application "Android Market" to "Google Play".
As soon as I pressed the "accept and download updates" button it started getting "process com.android.vending has stopped unexpectedly".

I research a little bit about this problem, I get the answers like

1. I have to reboot my phone.
2. I have to uninstall updates.
3. I have to uninstall the market application and reinstall it.

I want to know how I can fix this problem.

Comment: Have you cleared the app's cache? That did it for me.

Comment: Did you *try* the solutions you found?

Comment: i did clear the cache...but it didn't solve my problem....i m badly stuck up with this problem...

Answer (score 2):

Clearing the cache worked for me. `settings / applications / manage applications / google play store` and then clear data.

Comment: Clearing the cache and clearing all of the data are different. There is a "Clear Cache" button below the "Clear Data" button. You may need to scroll down a bit.

Comment: That's the most common solution to playstore probs -- works in 75% of all cases :) Just as Al said: Use the "clear cache" button, not "clear data". Guess it's a typo by Tom which he might want to correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the cache didn't work for me but uninstalling updates did work.

Comment: i did not found the uninstalling update...how can i do that...can u please explain me...

Comment: @Kri In settings - Applications - Manage Applications - All - Play Store. It's in the upper right corner.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Update to 2.3 for Play Store. Or root you OS , install XDA Assistant and uninstall the bundled Google Market. Now Install CWM , Download and install GAppsS. It will surely help.